# How many packages can one pc contain (without conflicts)?

Tags: linux, package-management, solaris, bsd, minix

I'm talking about one architecture, one distribution "at a time" (no multi-boot) and only packages in official repositories. If repos from different distros can be mixed, I'd like to distinguish between "pure distributions" (like "only `FreeBSD`") and "mixed distributions" (like "`debian` + `ubuntu` + `mint` + `NetBSD`").

I hope the answer doesn't depend a lot on the package manager...

Is there a way to "dry-run" (as `apt` calls it), like testing it on a (distribution) site?
How large/heavy would that system be?

How about having the same packages for several architectures, including a distribution and all (active) descended distributions (e. g. `OpenBSD` + `Fugulta` + `MirOS BSD`)?

If the question is too vague, a lower and upper border are also acceptable. I "know" that there's an objective answer, it's certainly just too computational intense for a private person.

Comment: I would say that *all* the packages in the official repositories should be tested to work alongside each other (with some exceptions, e.g. only one of LibreOffice and OpenOffice should be installed). I would strongly discourage mixing linux distros and installing packages from one distro into another distro. -- And I cannot give you a number.

Comment: When I try `# apt install x*`, it gives me conflicting packages, of which most don't seem to interact (but they obviously do).

Comment: Which linux distro and version are you running? Please tell us and we can look at the specific details of that distro and version. Are there some particular program packages or combination of packages, that create problems for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big players are Debian, Fedora, and ArchLinux and their derivatives.

Ubuntu

```
> apt list 2>/dev/null | grep bionic | wc -l
62007
```

CentOS

```
> yum list | grep "  " | wc -l
24758
```

As you note some of those may conflict, or be broken, etc.
Yes you can dry run, for example on arm64 Ubuntu;

```
> apt install * 2>/dev/null | grep "not installable" | wc -l
135
> apt install * 2>/dev/null | grep "Conflicts" | wc -l
903
> echo "62007-135-903" | bc
60969
```

So 60969 is probably as close a guess as you will get without actually installing everything for which you may want a fast VM with [~1 TB](https://www.debian.org/mirror/size) of free space.